# Procedure returning 'Cursor is closed'

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I am writing a stored procedure about get ticketlist. I want to control my input parameters null or not null for this I used to if elsif for example first input (username) is null and second input (ticketid) can be null and then third input (userid) has to be NOT NULL when I execute this procedure it is going directly else end I am getting "cursor is closed" error.

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE "TICKETLISTSEARCH" 
(
  p_UserName VARCHAR2,
  p_TicketID NUMBER,
  p_UserID NUMBER, 
  p_Cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS 
BEGIN
-- TicketID değeri dolu olan aramalarda
if (p_UserName = '' AND p_TicketID <> 0 AND  p_UserID = 0) THEN
IF NOT p_Cursor%ISOPEN THEN
OPEN p_Cursor FOR
SELECT TicketID
      ,CreateDate
      ,dateStart
      ,DealerUser
      ,(select UserID from ProductUser where UserID = T.NextUser) as UserID
      ,case when NextUser = 0 then 'ATAMA YOK' else (select UserName from Users where UserID = T.NextUser) END as FollowUser
      ,case when StatusID = 0 then 'Durum Bilgisi Girilmemiş' else (select Name from Status where StatusID = T.StatusID) END as Status
      ,P.Name as Product
      ,case when T.TalepID = 0 then 'Talep Türü Belirtilmemiş ' else (select Name from Talepler where TalepID = T.TalepID) END as Talep
      ,T.StatusID
      ,T.ProductID
      ,T.TalepID
      ,Title
      ,Explanation
      ,DateClose
  FROM Ticket T
  inner join Product P on (T.ProductID = P.ProductID)
--  inner join Status S on (T.StatusID = S.StatusID)
--  inner join Users U on (U.UserID = T.NextUser)
  WHERE
  T.TicketID = p_TicketID and T.StatusID not in (8)
  ORDER BY T.TicketID DESC;

END IF;
-- UserID değeri 0 olan kayıtları getir.
elsif (p_UserName = '' AND p_TicketID = 0 AND p_UserID <> 0) THEN
IF NOT p_Cursor%ISOPEN THEN
OPEN p_Cursor FOR
SELECT TicketID
      ,CreateDate
      ,dateStart
      ,DealerUser
      ,(select UserID from ProductUser where UserID = T.NextUser) as UserID
      ,case when NextUser = 0 then 'ATAMA YOK' else (select UserName from Users where UserID = T.NextUser) END as FollowUser
      ,case when StatusID = 0 then 'Durum Bilgisi Girilmemiş' else (select Name from Status where StatusID = T.StatusID) END as Status
      ,P.Name as Product
      ,case when T.TalepID = 0 then 'Talep Türü Belirtilmemiş ' else (select Name from Talepler where TalepID = T.TalepID) END as Talep
      ,T.StatusID
      ,T.ProductID
      ,T.TalepID
      ,Title
      ,Explanation
      ,DateClose
  FROM Ticket T
--  inner join Talepler TT on (T.TalepID=TT.TalepID)
  inner join Product P on (T.ProductID = P.ProductID)
--  inner join Status S on (T.StatusID = S.StatusID)
 -- inner join ProductUsers PU on (PU.UserID = T.NextUser)
  WHERE
  T.NextUser = p_UserID and T.StatusID not in (8)
  ORDER BY T.TicketID DESC;
END IF;

else dbms_output.put_line('HATA');
END IF;
END TICKETLISTSEARCH;
```

Comment: Code like `p_UserName = ''` will not work on Oracle, you have to write `p_UserName is null` instead.

Comment: Try changing the definition of p_Cursor to `p_Cursor IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR` and see if that helps. Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for both solution it's done! it worked